# Doubt about theorem 4.1.4 of Nonlinear Programming of Mokhtar Bazaraa

Tags: analysis

Regards.

I need help to understand the theorem 4.1.4 in the book Nonlinear Programming of Mokhtar Bazaraa.

The theorem says:

> Suppose that $ f: R^n \rightarrow R $ is twice differentiable at $ \overline{x} $. If $ \nabla f(\overline{x}) = 0 $ and $ H(\overline{x}) $ is positive definite, $ \overline{x} $ is a strict local minimum.

I don't understand this part:

> Suppose, by contradiction, that $ \overline{x} $ is not strict local minimum; that is, suposse that there exists a sequence $ \{ x_k \} $ converging to $ \overline{x} $ such that $ f(x_k) \leq f(\overline{x}), x_k \neq \overline{x} $, for each $ k $.

How I know that that sequence exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\overline x$ is not a strict local minimum, then every neighborhood of $\overline x$ contains points $z\neq x$ where the value of $f$ is $\leq$ its value at $\overline x$.  Apply that repeatedly, taking as your neighborhoods each of the balls around $\overline x$ of radius $1/k$.  That gives you, for each $k$ a point, called $z$ above, but which I'll now rename as $x_k$ to indicate that there's one such point for each $k$.  These points $x_k$ constitute the sequence you want.